# How to morph the shape of the blue shadow clicked indicator in CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/5wIqJTiPZtIzPcfw7m6H?p=preview)

```
.orange-circle-button {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: .5em solid #E84D0E;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #e84d0e;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 7em;
    width: 7em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the screen shot

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the blue shadow when clicked using CSS ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `outline: 0;` property. This will dissapear the border.

Though remember, it's not a good idea to remove the focus on elements just for vanity design, that could limit your content for visually impaired users or people who don't have a mouse. Instead, you can redefine that border with a `box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #000;`

Answer (score 1):

Using `outline: 0` usually does the trick. Firefox gets it right on your demo, but Chrome applies the outline by default.